# Add user to multiple groups with Puppet

Tags: puppet, usergroups

I'm attempting to assign users to multiple groups with a manifest, but am running into walls.

**Attempt 1:**

```
class usergroup {

  group { "user_one":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 500,
  }
  group { "user_two":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 501,
  }
  group { "dev_site_one":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 502,
  }
  group { "dev_site_two":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 503,
  }
  group { "dev_site_three":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 504,
  }

  user { "user_one":
      ensure => present,
      uid => 500,
      gid => 500,
      gid => 502,
      gid => 503,
      gid => 504,
  }
  user { "user_two":
      ensure => present,
      uid => 501,
      gid => 501,
  }

}
```

Running this:

```
puppet apply --noop ./init.pp
```

Yields:

> Error: Duplicate parameter 'gid' for on User[user_one] at
>   /etc/puppet/modules/webserver/manifests/init.pp:159 on node
>   my_web_server

**Attempt 2:**

I tried to break out each gid declaration like so:

```
class usergroup {

  group { "user_one":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 500,
  }
  group { "user_two":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 501,
  }
  group { "dev_site_one":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 502,
  }
  group { "dev_site_two":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 503,
  }
  group { "dev_site_three":
      ensure => present,
      gid => 504,
  }

  user { "user_one":
      ensure => present,
      uid => 500,
      gid => 500,
  }
  user { "user_one":
      gid => 502,
  }
  user { "user_two":
      ensure => present,
      uid => 501,
      gid => 501,
  }

}
```

Running this:

```
puppet apply --noop ./init.pp
```

Yields:

> Error: Duplicate declaration: User[user_one] is already declared in
>   file /etc/puppet/modules/webserver/manifests/init.pp:156; cannot
>   redeclare at /etc/puppet/modules/webserver/manifests/init.pp:160 on
>   node my_web_server

...where 160 is where I try to assign gid 502 to user_one.

**Question**

Is there a way to assign multiple groups with Puppet, or do I have to hand-assign these groups?

Comment: An additional advice: Question regarding puppet are better placed on http://serverfault.com/. There are more users subscribed to [puppet]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is a way!

Have a look at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#user.

The parameter *gid* specifies the user's primary group which must be unique. Additional groups can be specified with the *groups* parameter.

Assuming that *500* should be the primary group ...

```
user { "user_one":
    ensure => present,
    uid => 500,
    gid => 500,
    groups => [502, 503, 504],
}
```

... should do the job.

Comment: `Error: Parameter groups failed on User[user_one]: Group names must be provided, not GID numbers. at /etc/puppet/modules/webserver/manifests/init.pp:157`   Fixed by changing gid's to names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use the **name of group** too, look below.

```
group { "group_one": 
        ensure => present, 
        gid => 500,}

group { "group_two":
         ensure => present,
         gid => 501,}

 user { "user_one":
         ensure => present,
         comment => 'New user being created',   
         uid => 505,   
         groups => ["group_one","group_two"],}
```